# Dynamic title with Lift

Tags: scala, menu, lift, sitemap, title

I would like to know how I can change the title of lift Menu :

```
lazy val items: Menu = Menu.param[Page]("recents", S ? "baseline"+" | Page "+p, c => getPage(c), pc => pc.toString) / "page"  >>
        LocGroup("items") >> Hidden >> Template(() => Templates("items" :: "list" :: Nil) openOr NodeSeq.Empty)
```

Basically I want to display the page number in my title.

Comment: hope the discussion here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/liftweb/4ZvS3aKzFZ0 helps you

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer, but I figured I would post one here for reference.

There is a `LocParam` called [`Title`](http://liftweb.net/api/25-M4/api/scala/net/liftweb/sitemap/Loc%24%24Title.html) that will allow you to set the title of the page. I've added the param to your example, and you can see that the constructor accepts a function which takes an argument of type `Page` and returns a `NodeSeq` representing the title of the page.

```
lazy val items: Menu = Menu.param[Page](
  "recents", "recents", 
  c => getPage(c), pc => pc.toString) / "page"  >>
        LocGroup("items") >> 
        Hidden >>
        Template(() => Templates("items" :: "list" :: Nil) openOr NodeSeq.Empty) >>
        Title((p) => Text(S ? "baseline"+" | Page "+p))
```