# Why does Lift escape this <lift:bind> value?

Tags: scala, lift

I have (roughly) this LIFT-ified HTML in my default template:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>FooBar Application | <lift:bind name="page-title"/></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><lift:bind name="page-title" /></h1>
    <div id="page-content">
        <lift:bind name="page-content" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

...and then this in my main template:

```
<lift:surround at="page-content">
  <lift:bind-at name="page-title">Home</lift:bind-at>
</lift>
```

...which give me this in the generated HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>FooBar Application | &lt;lift:bind name=&quot;page-title&quot;/&gt;</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <div id="page-content">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why is the `<lift:bind>` tag in the `<title>` getting escaped, and the one in the `<body><h2>` not? And how do I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Are the pages defined through `SiteMap`? As was mentioned before, `<title>` can be a special case, and it is interpreted in several places - some of which might be doing the escaping. If you can, I'd try setting the page title in one of two ways:

Through the `Sitemap` you can use the `Title` `Loc Param` as referenced here: [Dynamic title with Lift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657651/dynamic-title-with-lift/14755517#14755517)

You can also have  something like: `<title data-lift="PageTitle"></title>` to have it invoke a snippet called `page-title`. Where, the snippet would be something like:

```
class PageTitle { 
  def render = "*" #> "FooBar Application | Home"
}
```